# Group action on fibre functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, group-actions, abelian-categories, tannakian-category

(I asked this question on mathstack here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413271/group-action-on-fibre-functor. After getting no response and being suggested in the comments to post it here, I am posting this here.)

Let $C$ be a neutral Tannakian category (ie. it is rigid tensor Abelian category where hom sets are $k$-vector spaces and End$(1)=k$ and there is a fibre functor $w$ from $C$ to category of vector spaces such that $w$ is a exact faithful tensor functor.)

Let group $G$ act on $C$ in the sense that for each $g \in G$ we have a functor $a_g : C \to C$ such that $a_g a_h$ and $a_{gh}$ are naturally isomorphic. Further assume the group acts by tensor functors.

> Simpson in his paper "Higgs Bundles and Local Systems" says that "by transport of structure, $G$ also acts on ${\rm End}(w,C)$ where the endomorphism algebra is just the endomorphism of the fibre functor."

> My question is : How do we get such an action?

A typical element in ${\rm End}(w,C)$ is a tuple ${f_V}$ where $f_V \in{\rm End}(w(V))$ and makes required diagrams commute. (It's just the data of natural transformation nothing else).

Comment: about the group action: does it commute also with the symmetric structure? that is, you have a collection of maps $a_g(X\otimes Y)\to a_g(X)\otimes a_g(Y)$, but do the compositions $a_g(X\otimes Y)\to a_g(Y\otimes X)\to a_g(Y)\otimes a_g(X)$ and $a_g(X\otimes Y)\to a_g(X)\otimes a_g(Y)\to a_g(Y)\otimes a_g(X)$ equal? If so, you can use the theory of Deligne on the uniqueness of such functors (assuming $k$ is algebraically closed)

Comment: Well the context was the $\mathbb C^*$ action on the category of Higgs bundles, so yes the two compostions in my case are equal. Can you elaborate on the statement you made regarding "the theory of Deligne on the uniqueness of such functors"?

Answer (score 3):

Deligne proved that assuming that $C$ is Tannakian and $K$-linear, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, then there is a unique fiber functor from C to $Vec_K$. If you have a symmetric monoidal functor $F:C\to D$, and you have forgetful functors $F_C:C\to Vec_K$ and $F_D:D\to Vec_K$ this implies in particular that the functors $F_DF$ and $F_C$ are equivalent, due to uniqueness.
Tannaka reconstruction tells you that $C\cong Rep-H_1$ and $D\cong Rep-H_2$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are some groups, reconstructed as $H_1=Aut(F_C)$ and $H_2=Aut(F_D)$. The equivalence $F_DF\cong F_C$ then gives you a homomorphism of groups $\phi:H_2\to H_1$, and it can be shown that $F$ is induced by the pullback along $\phi$. Moreover, the homomorphism $\phi$ is unique up to composition with conjugation in $H_1$.

In your case $C=D$, $H_1=H_2$ and $F=a_g$. So you get in fact a homomorphism of groups $G\to Out(H)$. There should be a reason why this is liftable to a proper action, not only an outer one, but I do not know the context well enough.